# Java string only contains numbers, spaces, and the symbols +-()

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java string and it's only allowed to contain the numbers 0 to 9, spaces, and the symbols + - ( )

How do I test this?

Comment: Have you looked into using regular expression?

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how regex works, it's just a confusing mess of symbols, so I was hoping someone here could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code checks if your string matches the regular expression pattern of any amount digits, +-() and spaces:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9+-]*\\)*\\(*\\s*)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println(b);
```

The + indicates that you have at least one of these allowed symbols. If you want to allow empty strings as well, just change the + to a *.

Answer (score 0):

try this regular expression:
[0-9.-\s+/()]+

With [This sample Program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)

Comment: nice question, but answers are already available every where.. What you need is more precisely searching.